# Pytorch: computing the eigenvector of data point

Tags: pytorch, svd

Lets say we already have estimated the principal directions and eigenvalues of a dataset `X` using pytorch:

```
U, S, V = torch.svd(X)
```

Now, given a new data point `x`, I'd like to estimate its eigenvector `v` representation given the already estimated principal directions:

```
U*S*v = x
```

Immedtiatly I'd think one would use `torch.solve(U*S, x)` for this, but it appears to only support square matrices. As a reminder, U*S is generaly not a square matrix, while `x` and `v` are vectors.